# Handling Form Post in asp.net MVC when dojo grid is present

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dojox.grid.datagrid

I am pretty new to web based applications development.I am using ASP.Net MVC4 with dojo toolkit. My requirement is like I have certain textboxes to capture data and also one dojo grid to capture certain details which are in a tabular format. So I am using Dojo grid(http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.8/dojox/grid/DataGrid) with ItemFileWriteStore. My view is like below(I am using razor)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateNewData", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))
{

    <div class="controlWrapper">
        <div class="controlLabel">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="controlValue">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="controlWrapper">
        <h4>
            Table Items</h4>
        <div id="myGrid">
        </div>
         <div id="addRemoveMode">
            <button data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" id="addButton" onclick="addRecord()">
                Add</button>
            <button data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" id="removeButton" onclick="removeRecord()">
                Remove Selected Rows
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

My java script to create grid is like below

```
require(["dojo/ready",
         "dojox/grid/DataGrid",
         "dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore",
         "dojo/json",
         "dojo/query",
         "dijit/form/TextBox"
        ], function (ready, DataGrid, ItemFileWriteStore, Json, query, TextBox) {
            ready(function () {

                var layout = [[
                { name: 'ID', field: 'ID', hidden: true },
                { name: 'Label', field: 'Label', width: '10%', editable: true },
                { name: 'Position', field: 'Position', width: '10%', editable: true }
                    ]];

                    var attCodeData = {
                                    identifier: 'ID',
                                    items: []
                                };
                console.log(globalVar);
                attCodeData["items"] = globalVar;

                myStore= new ItemFileWriteStore({ data: attCodeData })

                myGrid= new DataGrid({
                    store: myStore,
                    structure: layout,
                    rowSelector: '20px'
                },"divGrid");

                myGrid.startup();
}
```

My problem is since the grid is inside the form, whenever I add or remove a row, page is getting submitted to Post method mentioned in form. I just need to post the whole data so that I can process together. So I moved my grid outside Form. Now I am confused how to capture the whole data(data in text boxes and grid together) and submit to a controller method. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

To preventing whole page from getting submitted to Post method, you should use ajax solutions for sending and receiving data.

Take a look at this :[DataGrid View with "CRUD operations" using Dojo DataGrid, JsonRest Store, Entity Framework, SQL Server, ASP.NET MVC Web API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/331920/DataGrid-View-with-CRUD-operati)
and this: [Ajax with dojo/request](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/ajax/). I hope, they help.